# How to replace string with file contents which contains symbols using sed

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I have one word in one of my files and I want to substitute that word with xml file contents. considering that xml file contains some symbols which sed isn't able to process the command I am using isn't working. how can I fix this?

```
sed -i "s/test/$(cat header)/g" test.xml
```

Comment: Comment: it's better to ask this on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Can `test` occur anywhere in a line of text - or does it constitute a single complete line?

Comment: @steeldriver single

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
$ var="$(printf '%q' "$(cat header)")"
$ sed -i "s,test,$var,g" test.xml
```

Comment: approach works just when you echo it there are extra symbols. it looks like this $' text ' . can you correct it?

Comment: Does `header` contain Windows line endings? Run `unix2dos header` to get rid of them.

Answer (score 1):

If the word `test` is a complete line on its own, then instead of trying to use the `s` (substitute) command, you can use the `r` command to read contents from a file and insert it, deleting the original line after:

```
sed -e '/test/{r header' -e 'd;}' test.xml
```

This way avoids interpretation of shell-special characters, and also of regex metacharacters and characters such as `/` which are not special to the shell (and therefore not escaped by `printf '%q'` for example).

See also:

- [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script)

Comment: Is `/` regex metacharacter? I thought it's ``\`` like in `\b`. In my
example I intentionally used `,` as a delimiter - it's escaped
correctly by `printf %q`.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk you're right, that was bad terminology on my part - I'll see if I can come up with a better term